# echo a border bottom php

Tags: php, html, css

Is it possible to make a border at bottom using echo?

The reason i ask about this is that i cant find a good source that is directly an answer to my question. what i am trying to achieve here is to make a notification like that of facebook. This is because in my project i get the last 5 entry in database and i display it using echo so in order to distinguish the end of every entry i am thinking to make a border at bottom after every entry and suggestion is appreciated. This is how i display the data.

```
foreach (LoadEvent() as $value) {
    echo $value['searchresultwhat'];
    echo "<br/>\n";
    echo $value['searchresultwhen'];
    echo "<br/>\n";
    echo $value['searchresultwhere'];
    echo "<br/>\n";
    echo "<br/>\n";
}
```

Comment: use `<hr>` instead of `<br>`

Comment: You should do this in CSS.

Comment: @diEcho it work i want to give you a +1 what is hr  can you tell me just want to know about it i dont know it so might ask..

Comment: Open this link you will come to know what is hr tag:- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution is to use a `<hr />` (which is a horizontal rule, looks like the line below this paragraph) instead of `<br >`

---

The above line is a `<hr />`. You can use this in your code this way:

```
<?php
    foreach (LoadEvent() as $value)
    {
        echo $value['searchresultwhat'];
        echo "<hr/>\n";
        echo $value['searchresultwhen'];
        echo "<hr/>\n";
        echo $value['searchresultwhere'];
        echo "<hr/>\n";echo "<br/>\n";
    }
?>
```

But the preferred way is to use the CSS:

```
<?php
    foreach (LoadEvent() as $value)
    {
        echo "<div class='bb'>$value['searchresultwhat']</div>";
        echo "<div class='bb'>$value['searchresultwhen']</div>";
        echo "<div class='bb'>$value['searchresultwhere']</div>";
    }
?>
```

And give this in CSS:

```
.bb {border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try to add this line of code before the end of the foreach:

```
echo "<div style='border-bottom: 1px solid #000000'></div>";
```

It will be even better when you give the div a classname, and put the style-attribute in your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

You can stylize it using CSS3 selectors by this:

Let's say your results have class 'search-result' and it looks like this:

```
<div class="results">
   <div class="search-result">result 1 </div>
   <div class="search-result">result 2 </div>
   <div class="search-result">result 3 </div>
</div>
```

and into your CSS you should write this

```
.search-result:last-child {
```

border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

Do not use HR tag since it is deprecated and is very bad practice using it!